# Updating stock in run time while adding items to bill with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a billing application with C# windows ms access back-end. In the billing task i'm adding purchased items to bill and the same time i'm updating the stock of that item. Items stock got updated successfully in table.But when i load the updated stock in my textBox it requires an extra event to populate the textBox. I'm performing all the above task in a single button click. When adding the next item to bill and i press the add button...then the updated stock get loaded to the textbox of previous item. How can i load the textBox(in real Time) with current upadated stock when I add items to bill with a single button click with extra event?
what im doing is--

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calamnt();
        string ddd = textBox6.Text;
        if (textBox4.Text.Length != 0)
        {


                if (textBox14.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    string bid = getunique();
                    textBox14.Text = bid;
                }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text) <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No more stock");
            }
            else
            {
                bill();
                ddr.Clear();
                // button4.Enabled = true;
                load_bill();
                stock_update();
                textBox6.Enabled = false;
                unit_total += Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                // button4.Enabled = false;
                // dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();


            }
                //MessageBox.Show(code_total.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a phone no");
        }
```

//code for adding item to bill

```
calculate_purchase_amount();
        double qty = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        double camnt = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
       // double disc = Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text);
        double mr = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
       // actual_amount = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sd + "bowoni.accdb";
       string add_item = "insert into purchase(bill_id,customer_name,item_name,expire,batch,unit_price,qty,mrp,disc,amount)values('" + textBox14.Text + "','" + comboBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + textBox19.Text + "','" + textBox18.Text + "','" + camnt + "','" + qty + "','" + mr + "','" + disc + "','" + actual_amount + "')";
        OleDbCommand cmdbill = new OleDbCommand(add_item, conn);
        conn.Open();
        int xxt = cmdbill.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (xxt > 0)
        {
            flag = true;
           // MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfuly");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

//stock update

```
 double new_stock = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        double new_tot_purchase = new_stock * unit_pri;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sd + "bowoni.accdb";
        string updatestkfrom_bill = "update item set stock='" + new_stock + "',total_it='"+new_tot_purchase+"'where item_name='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updatestkfrom_bill, con);
        con.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(400);
        int xxt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (xxt > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("STock updated");
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();

             comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                OleDbDataReader odr;
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sd + "bowoni.accdb";

                conn.Open();
                string combo = "select * from item where item_name='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(combo, conn);
                odr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

                ds.Load(odr);

                Thread.Sleep(500);
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
                {
                    // dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    textBox4.Text = row[0]["stock"].ToString();

                }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general points:

1. You should use parameterized queries to prevent SQL-injection
2. You should give your variables meaningful names. It helps you maintaining your code later on (no `textBox1`, `textBox2`... are not meaningful names)
3. What about the `Thread.Sleep` statements? `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` are synchronous. They block the thread until the operation is finished. No needs for additional waits.
4. You should not do potentially blocking or long running operations (like database access) in the UI thread but use a background thread and update the UI when it's finished, because otherwise you app may look as it's freezed.
5. Your app is limited to one client only because you do the calculations of the stock on the client side. What if the same item is sold from another machine? The calculated stock in the database will be overwritten. Use a query like `UPDATE item SET stock = stock - @usedstock, total_it = total_it + @usedstock * @unitprice where item_name = @itemname` instead, so the data will be calculated in the database.

For your question: I don't see, how the `select` from the items table can ever be executed because you do

```
 comboBox2.Items.Clear();
 if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
```

The condition will always be `false`, as the purpose of `Clear()` is to remove all items, thus `Items.Count()` will be `0`.

Comment: thanx....for your answer..sir..i realy appreciating. For updating stock...i load the stock from table and then substrack the quantity from the stock...and update...is it ok?

Comment: I don't know your use case, so maybe client side updates may be ok as well. I just wanted to point out some (possible) weak spots, which may lead to errors. If the answer solved your problem, please don't forget to vote and/or accept

Comment: I really appreciate your answer...i have used backgroudworker..nut some some exception coming as..."Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Comment: Yeah, you can't update ui elements from a backthread but must use a dispatcher